# Right way to create index in Informix

Tags: sql, indexing, informix

On one of my Informix tables, there are two indexes that have only 1 different column out of three. Here are the indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX informix.ix_1
    ON informix.test(date, operator, rn)

CREATE INDEX informix.ix_2
    ON informix.test(choice, date, operator)

date is from type Date
operator is Char(3)
choice is Integer
rn is Integer
```

Is it smart to combine these indexes into one and drop them, in this way:

```
CREATE INDEX informix.ix_new
        ON informix.test(date, operator, rn, choice)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing what queries you run against that table, it isn't clear whether any of those indexes is useful.  The size of the table — both width (number of columns and their types) and length (number of rows) also factor into the equation.  Since the indexes are not unique, they're not present to enforce a key constraint.

If you always specify an exact date, the `ix_1` index can be used.  If you also specify an operator, it will be more useful (more restrictive); if you also specify the `rn`, it will be most useful.  If you don't specify the date, `ix_1` won't be used.

Similarly, with `ix_2`, if you always specify a choice, the index can be used; if you also specify the operator and date, it will be more useful (more restrictive).

With the new index, the 'choice' column will really only help if you always specify the date, operator and `rn`.

Remember that (non-unique) indexes represent a trade-off.  They have to be maintained, so when you add a new row, or update one of the indexed columns in an existing row, or delete a row, each of the indexes also has to be modified appropriately.  If the indexes are frequently used in between changes, then the cost of maintenance can more than pay for itself in the speed-up of the queries.  If you seldom query the table or the indexes are never used with the queries you run against the table, then the indexes are just storage overhead (and a marginal optimization overhead as they have to be studied to see if they can help with the query — but this is a second-order effect).  If the indexes speed up queries, their maintenance cost is not a problem.  If they're never used, they're so much wasted effort.

Unique indexes typically help enforce an database constraint, and are subject to different considerations, though there are many similarities.  If some combination of columns must be unique, the index serves a purpose even if it is never used in any query (though it is likely that the index *will* be used).

All of this applies pretty much to any database that uses indexes.  There are whole books written on the design of indexing schemes for particular database designs.

Answer (score 3):

Index design is based on the queries you need the index to support.

The order of columns in the index matters, and this also has to do with the queries you need the index to support.

You can't determine if it's smart to combine your indexes until you analyze your queries.

I don't use Informix regularly, but I see there is a chapter in the Informix Performance Guide about [Queries and the query optimizer](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.perf.doc/ids_prf_491.htm). You should read that guide to get more tips about how to analyze your queries.